# Get calling arguments for getter in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, getter

Given a javascript object like this:

```
var myThing = {};
Object.defineProperty(myThing, 'gen', {
    'get' : function() {
        // access caller name here, so I can return cool/neat stuff
    }
});
```

I want to be able to get children of myThing.gen, but know what is being asked for in the getter.

for example:

```
var coolThing = myThing.gen.oh.cool;
var neatThing = myThing.gen.oh.neat;
```

I want the "oh.cool" or "oh.neat" part in getter, so I can make decisions based on this, and return something specific to it. I am ok with solution not working in IE, or old browsers, as it is primarily for node.

The actual purpose of this is so that I can request `myThing.gen.oh.neat` and have the myThing.gen getter resolve to `require('./oh/neat.js')` and return it.

Since require cache's, this is an efficient way to dynamically load modular functionality, and have a tidy interface (rather than just dynamically building the require where needed) without having to know the structure ahead of time.

If there is no introspection-of-name function that can get this for me, I could just do something less elegant, like this:

```
myThing.gen = function(name){
    return require('./' + name.replace('.', '/') + '.js');
}
```

and do this:

```
neatThing = myThing.gen('oh.neat');
```

I don't like this syntax as much, though.  I looked at chai's dynamic expect(var).to.not.be.empty stuff, but couldn't figure out how to do it completely dynamically. Maybe there is not a way.

without actually solving the problem of dynamically discovering the caller, I can do this:

```
var myThing = {};
Object.defineProperty(myThing, 'gen', {
    'get' : function() {
        return {
          'oh':{
            'cool': require('./oh/cool.js'),
            'neat': require('./oh/neat.js')
          }
       };
    }
});
```

Is there a way to do this dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

You can't see what the property `gen` will be used for in the future, so you would need to return an object with properties that react to what the object is used for when it actually happens:

```
var myThing = {};
Object.defineProperty(myThing, 'gen', {
  'get' : function() {
    var no = {};
    Object.defineProperty(no, 'cool', {
      get: function(){ alert('cool'); }
    });
    Object.defineProperty(no, 'neat', {
      get: function(){ alert('neat'); }
    });
    return { oh: no };
  }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UjpGZ/1/

Comment: This still doesn't resolve being able to get the info dynamically. This solution is not much different than pre-filling the object (my second example), and doing an alert on get(). I updated my question with a use-case for what I actually need. Basically I just need to get the part after "gen", somehow.

Comment: @konsumer: You can't get the info dynamically. The property `gen` is not told what the result will be used for later on. Getting the info later on doesn't work either; if a property doesn't exist you will simply get `undefined` back when trying to access it, the object won't be asked to create the property. Note that this solution allows you to require only the files used, instead of requiring all the files to pre-fill the object.

Comment: You're going to have to wait for ES6 "Proxy" objects.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I found too. It seemed like chai was doing something similar (order doesn't matter, chaining seems kind of dynamic, and some keywords don't do anything, like "to" & "be" for example) but it seems like it prefills.

Comment: @konsumer: Chaining like that is just a kind of state machine. The properties of an object simply returns the same object with a changed state. When some methods have been called, the object has accumulated different states, and does something accordingly. There is nothing dynamic about it, the different methods are all defined beforehand.

Comment: Yep, it's just prefilled chains of methods on the same object-type (Assertion)

Comment: Also, I can't seem to get the full name using using harmony Proxy, just the last var-name, if I return the same proxy in the get.  see my example: https://gist.github.com/konsumer/6361801 Does anyone have experience with Proxy?